# I can drag elements outside the document window, but not outside a simple div. Why?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mousemove

I'm trying to drag things out of my document by capturing the mouse coordinates and moving stuff accordingly. Currently I use document.addEventListener and this works well even if I drag stuff outside the window. The functionality is increasing and to keep up with the complexity I would rather use divs and div1.addEventListener instead.

But this change doesn't let me drag things outside my div, let alone outside my window. I'm talking about dragging only (mouse down inside the div and then dragging the mouse out of it). It brakes down as soon as I'm outside the div.

I don't get what is going on, I experimented with it a long time ago and I remembered this to be working code.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VC64T/)

```
window.onload = function()
{
    div1 = document.getElementById("div1");

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt){mouseDown(evt, this)}, false);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){mouseMove(evt, this)}, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt){mouseUp(evt, this)}, false);

    // div1.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt){mouseDown(evt, this)}, false);
    // div1.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){mouseMove(evt, this)}, false);
    // div1.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt){mouseUp(evt, this)}, false);
}

function mouseMove(evt, caller)
{
}

function mouseDown(evt, caller)
{
}

function mouseUp(evt, caller)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the coordinates of the div are not changing, it stops getting mouseMove events when the drag is outside its bounds.

Comment: but the same is true for document if the mouse leaves the window

Comment: I'd have to go back and read the spec to be sure, but I think the window is a special case. Depending on the browsers you need to support, I recommend reading up on HTML5 drag and drop API. It might make your life a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: HTML drag and drop is something special. I'm not dragging HTML elements. I'm dragging shapes on canvas. I think I should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: I searched the web and it seems impossible. However, I checked some code I wrote for the iPhone about a month ago and there I could do it. Which is strange because it uses webkit just like Chrome and it does not work in Chrome. Weird. The code was a little bit more verbose though, but still.